# fetch delete request returns: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': 'DELETE' is unsupported in no-cors mode

Tags: reactjs, fetch, serverless, http-delete

```
i have a lamda delete request on aws serverless in there ive wrote in serverless.yaml all the
```

cors needed :  cors:

STILL  im getting errors that DELETE' is unsupported in no-cors mode.

```
did anyone had the same problem?

Thank you



            origin: '*' # <-- Specify allowed origin
            headers: # <-- Specify allowed headers
              - Content-Type
              - X-Amz-Date
              - Authorization
              - X-Api-Key
              - X-Amz-Security-Token
              - X-Amz-User-Agent


and in my ui(react js),    i have the fallowing fetch request : 

const delteFoster = async (delid) =>  await fetch('URL' + delid, {
   method: "DELETE",
   cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
   credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
   mode:'no-cors',
   headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  },
  })
  .then(res => res.text()) // or r
```

even when i remove the 'no cors' attr in my request i still have the allow origin header and its not wotking